# ngb-accordion from Angular2 ng-bootstrap not showing on view

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Although my HTML loads (able to see `"HI", "title1", "objName11"` due to the `span` tags on top.), **the ngb-accordion doesn't get rendered** on the view.
I am not able to figure out what I missed.

There is no compilation/build error. No errors on Console. :(

I saw something about NGB-PRECOMPILE, is this necessary? Also not able to find it in @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792108/precompile-error-on-ng-bootstrap-ngb-precompile

Following are the code snippets, 
*(i have simplified the code a lot by removing `onInit` implementation where I used services/observables to actually load the `MyObject`, just to be to the point)*

My Template: ./someComponent.Component.html:

```
     <span>Hi<span>
     <span>myObject.objList[0].title</span>
     <span>myObject.objList[0].details[0].objName</span>
     <ngb-accordion>
        <ng-panel *ngFor="let myObj of myObject.objList">
            <template ngbPanelTitle>

                        <span>{{myObj.title}}</span>

            </template>
            <template ngbPanelContent>
                <div *ngFor="let detail of myObj.details" class="row">
                    <span>
                        {{detail.objName}}
                    </span>

            </template>
        </ng-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  NGB_ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES }  from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion';
import { MyObject } from './MyObject.model';



@Component({
    selector: 'some-selector',
    templateUrl: './someComponent.Component.html',
    directives: [ NGB_ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES ],

})
export class SomeComponent {
   public myObject: MyObject = {
                        objList: [
                              { title: "title1",
                                details: [{ objName: "objName11" }, 
                                          { objName: "objName12" }]
                              },
                              { title: "title2",
                                details: [{ objName: "objName21" }, 
                                          { objName: "objName22" }]
                              }};

}
```

MyObjectModel:

```
export class MyObject{
         objList: ObjList[];
}

export class ObjList{
    title:string;
    details: Detail[];
}

export class Detail{
      objName:string;
}
```

Comment: Following are the dependencies I have:

"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.2",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.15"

Comment: Update: in @angular/compiler 2.0.0-rc5, the precompile was changed to entryComponents.

Comment: Have you definitely got a line like ``  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">`` in the src/index.html ?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I have.

Answer (score 0):

This is so embarrassing and kind of frustrating. I was so involved trying to find out which style/library/module missing, i lost 2 whole days on this.

One up-thing though, i had some more insights into Ang2 Directives, entryComponent (precompile) etc.

The issue was with

```
<ng-panel *ngFor="let myObj of myObject.objList">
```

for it should have been

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let myObj of myObject.objList">
```

Just to summarize,
all that you need for the ngb-bootstrap components is:

1) having reference to your NGB directives in your component:

```
import {  NGB_ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES }  from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion';
```

2) within decorator:

```
directives: [ NGB_ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES ],
```

3) No need of `entryComponents`
4) in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule,

    ]})
```

Answer (score 0):

two things you need to fix:

1. "template" to "ng-template"
2. "ng-panel" to "ngb-panel"

So the code should be:

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let myObj of myObject.objList">
                    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>

                                <span>{{myObj.title}}</span>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                        <div *ngFor="let detail of myObj.details" class="row">
                            <span>
                                {{detail.objName}}
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
```

hope it helps. It works on my side